# R: Attribute value to a column according to corresponding between two others columns

Tags: r

I am a beginner on R and I don't find an answer to, what I think, is a classic question.

I have a dataframe, let's say :

```
  df <- data.frame(
        id1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
        id2 = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 1),
        Value = c(2005, NA, 2002, NA, NA))
```

| id1 | id2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2005 |
| 2 | 6 | NA |
| 3 | 7 | 2002 |
| 4 | 8 | NA |
| 5 | 1 | NA |

I would like to change Value according to the matching between id1 and id2. For example, id1=1 and id2=5, so when id1=5 and id2=1, I attribute the value of 2005 at id1=5.

Ideally, I will obtain something like this:

| id1 | id2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2005 |
| 2 | 6 | NA |
| 3 | 7 | 2002 |
| 4 | 8 | NA |
| 5 | 1 | 2005 |

Or like that:

| id1 | id2 | Value | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2005 | NA |
| 2 | 6 | NA | NA |
| 3 | 7 | 2002 | NA |
| 4 | 8 | NA | NA |
| 5 | 1 | NA | 2005 |

I hope this is not a too asked question and that I have been comprehensible.

Thank you by advance for any help !

Antoine

Answer (score 0):

Create a `match` between the 'id' columns to return index, and then get the 'Value' corresponding to that index

```
df$Value2 <- with(df, Value[match(id2, id1)])
```

-output

```
> df
  id1 id2 Value Value2
1   1   5  2005     NA
2   2   6    NA     NA
3   3   7  2002     NA
4   4   8    NA     NA
5   5   1    NA   2005
```

---

Or if we need to update the original column, use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
df$Value <- with(df, coalesce(Value, Value[match(id2, id)]))
```